# Docker initiate the connection to archive.ubuntu

Tags: windows, ubuntu, docker, windows-7, virtual-machine

I have managed to install docker into my machine which is using Windows 7. My machine is under corporate network. As i am trying to learn docker i was following this [guide](https://docs.docker.com/engine/getstarted/step_four/#step-3-learn-about-the-build-process). When my Dockerfile is executing:

```
RUN apt-get -y update && apt-get install -y fortunes
```

which is perform ubuntu update and installing fortunes i get the following error:

```
cannot initiate the connection to archive.ubuntu.com:80. and - connect <101:network is unreachable>
```

In order to solve my problem, first i connected to my vm machine and i located the /etc/resolv.conf file where i modify it to add google dns

```
namespace 8.8.8.8
```

but that seems to not solve the issue when i exited and rebuild my Dockerfile.

As my machine is on windows i haven't found a solution for this problem. Does anyone know how should i surpass this problem?

Answer (score 0):

You have to start your `dockerd` (docker daemon) with same nameserver of your windows computer network settings and then your container and  image will get the connectivity from outside network/internet.

For more details Please visit this official link from docker :https://docs.docker.com/docker-for-windows/#network

Comment: Thanks. This is for windows 8 and above. Locally i am using docker toolbox. I followed [this](https://github.com/docker/kitematic/issues/1633) tutorial after i installed the toolbox. Simply i set the HTTP_PROXY and HTTPS_PROXY values to the corporate values. It worked and help me with running the hello-world app or any other app from docker repo. The problem with the [tutorial](https://docs.docker.com/engine/getstarted/step_four/#step-3-learn-about-the-build-process)  is in step 3 where it says that it creates a temporally container which they don't pick those values.